# Loading text in to mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem while doing work in MySQL 5 ,when I want to load data into a table from a text input file I get the message:  `Unknown database n`

My input is:

```
Sim cat male    \n
rim dog female  \n
kin fog male    \n
```

and my SQL code is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D/pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet
-> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Please try and explain your issue properly and format your code when you are writing something up and try to use proper words instead of "plz" :) It'll stop people downvoting and such.

Answer (score 1):

Without a [`USE database_name;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html) query first, MySQL doesn't know which database to look for the `pet` table in.